# How to restrict user from submitting a form twice in sharepoint?

Tags: forms, sharepoint, block

I'm working on a sharepoint forms

And I need to block edition for users after they submitted a date (data format), but I don't know if sharepoint allows it

Someone knows how can I do it?

Comment: This question might be better suited for sharepoint.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can add a rule that - 'check for duplicate entry'

Comment: You know which rule can I use?

Comment: Are you using infopath ? and where are you saving your data ? also are you using c# ?

Answer (score 0):

For OOB list form, you could use [presaveaction](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31330.sharepoint-using-presaveaction-function-on-custom-list-forms.aspx) to do client validation.

In this function, you could call rest api to check whether the item submitted already, if submitted, return false then the form won't be saved.

Sample demo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/JS/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function PreSaveAction() {
            var check = false;
            var listid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.replace('{', '').replace('}', '');
            $.ajax({
                url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists(guid'" + listid + "')/items",
                type: 'GET',
                async: false,
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                    "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    var count = data.d.results.length;
                    if (count < 5) {
                        check = true;
                    } else {
                        alert('over max items');
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }
            })
            return check;
        }
    </script>
```